# How can I best add connector to kafka connect in docker compose?

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Right now I have a docker compose that creates the Kafka cluster and Kafka connect. It also creates a shell container which I use to send a POST with the configuration to add a new connector. How can I setup the docker compose to add a connector (with my configuration) AFTER kafka connect is ready?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cURL request does exactly that - waits for the Connect REST API to be available, then creates the connector if it doesn't already exist.

One "better" way would not to use Compose, and instead k3s or Minikube w/ Strimzi Operator with KafkaConnect resource type where you can define Connectors as YAML config rather than HTTP+JSON requests.

Comment: I mean, Kubernetes operator still uses HTTP, but it's abstracted away